# How to set logging.file.name through command line arguments in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, logging

I am setting the `logging.file.name` in `application.properties` file which I want to pass as command line argument. Is it possible?
The reason is I am trying to run multiple jar files from a single application and I want to display logs of each application run at a single location.

Comment: `--logging.file.name=yourfile.txt` should already work. If it doesn't, try `-Dlogging.file.name=yourfile.txt`. If it doesn't, do you get any errors?

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot provides several options to [externalize configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.4/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config).

> Spring Boot uses a very particular `PropertySource` order that is
> designed to allow sensible overriding of values. Properties are
> considered in the following order (with values from lower items
> overriding earlier ones):
>
> 1. Default properties (specified by setting `SpringApplication.setDefaultProperties`).
> 2. `@PropertySource` annotations on your `@Configuration` classes. Please note that such property sources are not added to the
>    Environment until the application context is being refreshed. This is
>    too late to configure certain properties such as `logging.*` and
>    `spring.main.*` which are read before refresh begins.
> 3. Config data (such as `application.properties` files).
> 4. A `RandomValuePropertySource` that has properties only in `random.*`.
> 5. OS environment variables.
> 6. Java System properties (`System.getProperties()`).
> 7. JNDI attributes from `java:comp/env`.
> 8. `ServletContext` init parameters.
> 9. `ServletConfig` init parameters.
> 10. Properties from `SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON` (inline JSON embedded in an environment variable or system property).
> 11. Command line arguments.
> 12. `properties` attribute on your tests. Available on `@SpringBootTest` and the test annotations for testing a particular
>     slice of your application.
> 13. `@TestPropertySource` annotations on your tests.
> 14. Devtools global settings properties in the `$HOME/.config/spring-boot` directory when devtools is active.

So you should be possible to override the values defined in your `application.properties` by setting environment variables, Java system properties, or command line arguments:

- Environmant variables: `export LOGGING_FILE_NAME=yourfile.txt`
- Java system property: `-Dlogging.file.name=yourfile.txt`
- Command line argument: `--logging.file.name=yourfile.txt`